# Error object printing differently when wrapped in Backtick `${error}`

Tags: javascript, typescript, error-handling

Axios is being used to make a 3rd party REST call. Frequently **Timeout Error** is received at this.

```
axios({
          url,
          method: 'post',
          headers,
          data: xml,
          timeout,
          proxy,
        }).then((response) => {
          resolve(response);
        }).catch(error => {
          console.log(error);    // prints big object
          console.log(${error}); // prints just a line
        });
```

If I print Timeout Error through `console.log()` it prints as below:

```
{
  "name": "insurance-service",
  "hostname": "adi",
  "pid": 30101,
  "level": "FATAL",
  "err": {
    "message": "timeout of 30000ms exceeded",
    "name": "Error",
    "stack": "Error: timeout of 30000ms exceeded\n    at /home/adi/workspace/insurance-service/dist/modules/health_insurance/providers/hdfc/optimarestore/integration.js:139:23\n    at Parser.<anonymous> (/home/adi/workspace/insurance-service/node_modules/xml2js/lib/parser.js:304:18)\n    at Parser.emit (events.js:315:20)\n    at Parser.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)\n    at SAXParser.onclosetag (/home/adi/workspace/insurance-service/node_modules/xml2js/lib/parser.js:262:26)\n    at emit (/home/adi/workspace/insurance-service/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:624:35)\n    at emitNode (/home/adi/workspace/insurance-service/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:629:5)\n    at closeTag (/home/adi/workspace/insurance-service/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:889:7)\n    at SAXParser.write (/home/adi/workspace/insurance-service/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:1436:13)\n    at Parser.exports.Parser.Parser.parseString (/home/adi/workspace/insurance-service/node_modules/xml2js/lib/parser.js:323:31)\n    at Parser.parseString (/home/adi/workspace/insurance-service/node_modules/xml2js/lib/parser.js:5:59)\n    at Object.exports.parseString (/home/adi/workspace/insurance-service/node_modules/xml2js/lib/parser.js:369:19)\n    at HDFCOptimaRestore.getErrorResultFromProposalXml (/home/adi/workspace/insurance-service/dist/modules/health_insurance/providers/hdfc/optimarestore/integration.js:132:26)\n    at /home/adi/workspace/insurance-service/dist/modules/health_insurance/providers/hdfc/optimarestore/integration.js:119:26\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)"
  },
  "msg": "timeout of 30000ms exceeded",
  "src": {},
  "v": 0,
  "timestamp": "2021-05-10T06:50:26.211Z"
}
```

But, if I do it like `${error}`, it just prints a single line as below. [here **error** is the argument of catch()]

```
Error: timeout of 30000ms exceeded
```

Why are these 2 behaving differently ?

Comment: You are converting the error to string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to special behavior of `console.log`.

When you pass it an object, the *whole object* will be logged, which will be navigable and expandable from the browser console - for ease of debugging.

When you turn it into a string with a template literal, *only that static string* will be displayed.

Apparently

```
Error: timeout of 30000ms exceeded
```

is what coercing the Error object into a string results in.

Answer (score 2):

```
console.log(error);
```

prints the whole object.

```
console.log(`${error}`);
```

prints the string representation ([Object.prototype.toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) / [Error.prototype.toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/toString)).